# Drag and drop from recycle to another view

Tags: android, kotlin

I need a help. I have a case such at [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KnUR.png)

I need to release drag and drop function from recycler to my custom view. My custom view is a container with four another views inside. This views have two types: empty and view that contains item from recycle. And when user dragging item from recycler I need change background color of some view in my container when view which I dragging moving inside bounds of view. So I know that OnDragListener handling events only inside parent view. Then I wrote two OnDragListeners for items in recycler and for my container view like:

```
interface DragItemListener {
        fun onDragItem(item: item?)
}


class DragController(val item: Item) : OnDragListener {

        override fun onDrag(v: View, event: DragEvent): Boolean {

            val action = event.action

            when (action) {
                DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED -> {
                    dragItemListener?.onDragItem(item)
                }
                DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
                    dragItemListener?.onDragItem(null)
                }
            }

            return true
        }

    }


class MyCustomContainer(context: Context) : LinearLayout(context) {

init {
   this.setOnDragListener(DraggingItemListener())
}

fun setDraggableElement(item: Item?) {
   this.draggedItem = item
}

private fun findItemView(x: Float, y: Float) : View?{

        (0 until childCount).map { getChildAt(it) }.forEach { 
            if (it is EmptyView || it is ItemView) {
                val bounds = getViewBounds(it)

                if (x > bounds.left && x < bounds.right && y > bounds.top && y < bounds.bottom){
                    it.setBackgroundResource(R.color.selected_background)
                    return it
                }else {
                    it.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background)
                }
            }
        }
        return null
} 

private fun getViewBounds(view: View) : Rect{
        return Rect(view.left, view.top, view.left + view.width, view.top + view.height)
}

inner class DraggingItemListener : OnDragListener {

        private var currentView: View? = null

        override fun onDrag(v: View?, event: DragEvent): Boolean {
            if (draggedItem != null) {

                when(event.action) {

                    DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION -> {
                        currentView = findItemView(event.x, event.y)
                    }
                    DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
                        when(currentView) {
                            is EmptyView -> {

                            }
                            is ItemView -> {

                            }
                        }
                    currentView?.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background)
                    currentView = null
                    }
            }else{
                currentView = null
            }
            return true
        }

    }

}
```

Is it correct way to resolve my issue or Im wrong? However it works fine